# On fresh Conda installation of PyProj: pyproj unable to set database path. _pyproj_global_context_initialize()

Tags: python, anaconda, miniconda, pyproj

I want to use `PyProj`. I follow the [installation instructions given in the documentation](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/installation.html)

```
conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
conda config --set channel_priority strict
conda install pyproj
```

When I run

```
from pyproj import CRS
```

I am getting

> C:\Users...\Miniconda3\envs\geopandas\lib\site-packages\pyproj_*init*_.py:89: UserWarning: pyproj unable to set database path.
> _pyproj_global_context_initialize()

**Some information on Python and my system**

Python version
-> 3.9.7 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Sep 29 2021, 19:15:42) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]

Operation System Information
-> Windows-10-10.0.19042-SP0

Answer (score 15):

**Quick an dirty**

Make sure you are in you environment with `conda activate YOUR_ENV`:

```
conda remove --force pyproj
```

This removes the library from the `conda environment`. Then do a

```
pip install pyproj
```

Now I do not get the error upon calling `from pyproj import CRS`.

**Proper way**

However, this is not going through to the core of the problem. I had conflicting versions of the proj.db. Check the value of the PROJ_LIB environment variable. Mine pointed to an installation of postgis. This helps to solve it: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#internal-proj-error-sqlite-error-on-select

How did I find the path to the installation of `proj`?
I looked into this file `...Miniconda3\envs\<ENV>\conda-meta\proj-<VERSION>-h1cfcee-<VERSION>.json` and searched for `\pkgs\\proj`. Once found, I checked the versins of `PROJ` installed in this folder `C:...\Miniconda3\pkgs\`. There are folder named something like `proj-<VERSION>-h1cfcee-<VERSION>`. Make sure the folder name is the exact same name you found this file links to:  `...Miniconda3\envs\<ENV>\conda-meta\proj-<VERSION>-h1cfcee-<VERSION>.json`. Finally I set my environment variable to the version needed `...Miniconda3\pkgs\proj-<VERSION>-h1cfcee-<VERSION\Library\share\proj`.